# ¿Cómo convertir encriptación usando BouncyCastle de C# a Java?

Tags: java, c#

Tengo el siguiente código de encriptación en C#

```
IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
cipher.Init(true, new ParametersWithIV(ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", keyBytes), counter));
byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.DoFinal(inputBytes);

return encryptedBytes;
```

Deseo convertir a su sintaxis correspondiente a Java, pero en Java no existe `CipherUtilities`, ni tampoco el objeto recibe en el método `Init` un `ParametersWithIV`.

Comment: Hola , creo que este articulo explica lo que necesitas : https://steelmon.wordpress.com/2013/07/01/simple-interoperable-encryption-in-java-and-net/

Comment: El detalle es que se utiliza Bouncy Castle con CTR, en el artículo que me pasaste se usa AES con CBC

Comment: intenta esto :

byte[] iv = new byte[16];
Arrays.fill(iv, (byte)0);    

SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
byte[] encrypted=cipher.doFinal(msgBytes);

Comment: Tampoco funciona porque el método Cipher.init() no posee el constructor (int,SecretKeySpec,byte[])